# Informix connections stored in Session

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-mvc-5, informix, idisposable

Good day!

I'm developing a web application to access an ancient Informix 7.31.UC4 database with IBM Informix Client SDK for .NET. The system is currently built so that each user must connect with his own DBMS credentials (not Identity credentials) which means that I either must

a) connect with different credentials upon each request which is way to slow (over 5 sec for creating, opening and closing connection, not to say about queried themselves)

or b) somehow store connections in Dictionary by username and make use of their pooling and avoid multiple connections for the same user in different sessions

or c) store a connection for each Session.

The first approach is unacceptable for its low speed. The second and the third approaches give me no way of disposing the IfxConnection : IDisposable, which makes me cry.

Am I missing a way to dispose objects stored in session upon session abandoning or ending? Is there a way to take advantages of the connection pooling in case of multiple sets of credentials? Or is it just that the system has been ill-designed in the first place and I should not care?

The only way I currently see is to create an Informix user with sufficient rights and keep one connection with pooling and use another SQLServer database for storing users and roles while ruling all the rights and roles at Controller level, but database designer won't hear me out.

P.S. I've seen several questions about disposable objects in sessions, all say it's bad, but I see no other option.

Comment: upgrade the database , same as the version 12.10 Innovator-C edition (free) is out of question?  (more information about the [editions here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0801doe/index.html)

Comment: ceinmart, unfortunately there's no such option.